# Excel VBA Timestamp in a cell when "Yes" is selected in the previous cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I need VBA code to automatically enter a Timestamp in cells located on column "L" when the "Yes" text is entered in the cell on the preceding column "K".

The Timestamp should be in format `MM-DD-YYYY` and shouldn't change unless the word "YES" is removed from the preceding cell.

Answer (score 1):

**This VBA (Macro) code will help you to achieve the goal.**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Range
Set r = Target

If Intersect(Range("K:K"), r) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If r.Value = "" Then r.Offset(0, 1) = "" 
If r.Value <> "YES" And r.Value <> "Yes" And r.Value <> "yes" Then Exit Sub


Application.EnableEvents = False


    If r.Value = "YES" Or r.Value = "Yes" Or r.Value = "yes" Then
    r.Offset(0, 1) = Now()
    r.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"

    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

 End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Right-click the **Sheet Tab** or press 
  **Alt+F11**.
- This brings up the VB Editor Window, 
  **Copy** and **Paste** this Code as 
  **Standard Module**.

**Edited:**

- This code will check the Criteria in all 
  three possible formats, **Upper Case**, 
  **Sentence Case** and in **Lower Case**, 
  before update adjacent cell with
  *Timestamp*.
- Also remove *Timestamp* from 
  adjacent Cell, if & when the  Criteria 
  will be deleted.

---

**N.B.**

- As soon you enter the Criteria **YES** or 
  **Yes** or even **yes** in any cells of 
  `Column K`, this code will  write   `Timestamp` is adjacent Cell in `Column L`.
- *In this code Column K and it's adjacent 
  Column is editable.*

Comment: This code will give wrong result when Target contains more than one cell (while copy-paste or auto-fill). You must iterate over Intersect() result.

Comment: @Akina, no it's working one to one,, read cavity I've written as soon you write Yes in any Cell in Col K , code will enter Timestamp in adjacent cell in Column L,, if Yes in K1 the Timestamp in L1 ☺

Comment: @Akina,, I always test properly the code or Formula before I post it as Answer ,, and it has been tested also,,!

Comment: Insert "Yes" to K1. L1 is filled. Insert "No" to K2. L2 is not filled. Select J1:K2. Press Ctrl-C. Select J3. Press Ctrl-V. And enjoy your "proven" result.

Comment: @Akina, read what OP has written,, **Timestamp in cells located on column "L" when the "Yes" text is entered in the cell on the preceding column "K".** and it's the reason code is not responding anything other tan `Yes` !!

Comment: OP had not specified the way for column K values are entered into. Why do you think it is typing strongly? In any case, it is bad when some actions (perhaps even erroneous) can lead to a program error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92243/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-akina).

Comment: Additionally. 1) The checking word MUST be case insensitive (OP says "Yes" and "YES" in two different places). 2) Your code do not protect from direct Lx altering (OP says *and shouldn't change unless the word "YES" is removed*, so you must restore the value if it is changed from sone another way than your code).

Answer (score 1):

Another way of making the same thing as Rajesh S, but with a slightly different approach.

Paste the code in the sheet that is to be used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim x As Range
If Target.Count < 1000 Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each x In Target
    If Not Intersect(Range("K:K"), x) Is Nothing Then
        If UCase(x.Value) = "YES" Then
            x.Offset(0, 1) = Now()
            x.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"
        Else
            x.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
        End If
    End If
    Next x
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```